# Visual Studio 2017 - How to get rid of split view bar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How to get rid of bar marked on below screenshot? Previously I had there some kind of code tracking, like code minimap, using which I could quickly move to specific part of my code, but I decided to remove it. It worked, but bar remained and it is misleading for me, as it cuts my code (it can also be seen on screenshot) and just waste space.

[image: This]

I remember that I saw this feature for first time in Visual Studio Code, but disabling it was easy as it required only to add one line to settings JSON file. Unfortunately, I can't see such a file for Visual Studio 2017. On the other side - last time Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio Code acted like two separate beings and that's fine for me. This time they act like Visual Studio 2017 inherits settings from Visual Studio Code. I had this code minimap though I never enabled it. I had ESLint enabled in Visual Studio 2017 though I never enabled it. However both of those were enabled in Visual Studio Code. Is there a way to separate Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio Code again? I would like my settings from Visual Studio Code to not be adopted by Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. I had to enter Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Scroll Bars and changed Behavior from "Use map mode for vertical scroll bar" to "Use bar mode for vertical scroll bar".

My question about inheriting settings from Visual Studio Code by Visual Studio 2017 is still up-to-date.

[image: This]